# ¿Una oración condicional o concesiva?

Tags: sintaxis

¿Qué tipo de oraciones introduce la conjunción **a no ser que**: condicionales o concesivas?

*No debía tener más de veinte años, y no parecía con ánimos de carnaval, **a no ser que estuviera disfrazada de inválida**.*

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

**"A no ser que"** es una conjunción **condicional**. Generalmente es idéntica a **"a menos que"**.

Ambas funcionan "al revés" de las condicionales típicas (como *"si", "siempre y cuando", "si es que", "en caso de"*, etc.): lo que indican es que la afirmación anterior será verdadera si **no** se da la condición expresada a continuación, o como tú lo dices, introducen una oración condicional.

En tu ejemplo, la mujer podría tener menos de 20 años siempre y cuando no estuviera disfrazada. *No estar disfrazada* es la condición.

En cambio, las conjunciones *concesivas* sirven para indicar que hay un obstáculo que no impide que lo afirmado sea verdadero: *iré aunque llueva*. Las principales conjunciones concesivas son *"aunque"* y "*a pesar de*".

Answer (score 0):

*a no ser que estuviera* activa la condicionalidad de la situación pero en una imaginaria del presente:

> No debía tener más de veinte años, y no parecía con ánimos de carnaval, **a no ser que estuviera** disfrazada de inválida. (*Pero no está disfrazada*.)